# How to check if user touched anything?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-window

I want to know when the user is interacting with my app. I've tried to use `Window.Callback` but I faced an issue with Toolbar.

In case we call `setSupportActionBar` (`setActionBar`) my `Window.Callback` doesn't receive events anymore.

**Restriction:**

I can't extend `Activity`. I need one global place to handle all interactions with the app.

Comment: You could try to extend `Activity`, override `setSupportActionBar` and add your implementation of `Window.Callback` after calling `super.setSupportActionBar`

Comment: No need to implement your custom `Window.Callback`, because `Activity` already implement it.

Comment: Thanks, it's possible but I'm looking for a solution without extending Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try [onUserInteraction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onUserInteraction()).

> Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the activity. Implement this method if you wish to know that the user has interacted with the device in some way while your activity is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with overriding `onUserInteraction` method on your activity

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
  //do what you like here
}
```

See docs for furhter informations  [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29)